# How to shift color of part of an image with ImageSharp?

Tags: c#, image-processing, imagesharp

I need to make a highlighter effect as if drawing with a transparent ink.

How do I do this in ImageSharp (or any other C# image processing library)?

Example Image:

[image: Image where some text is highlighted with a transparent color]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I can just set alpha on the pen's color to something other than 255 in ImageSharp.